# Creating an icon with transparency (alpha channel) from a bitmap

Tags: winapi, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm looking for a way to create an icon for the system tray application that displays information using a number that appears on it.

Creating a DC and drawing the number on it is not a problem (even with an alpha channel), but I could not in any way transfer it to the icon correctly.

Here's something I tried recently, which seems close to what I need, but when I try to draw it in a window (using DrawIconEx) it shows a black square around the digits, not the window background.

Can someone direct me to correct this code so that the transparency is transferred correctly?

Thank you!

```pascal
function CreateHiColorIcon(DC: HDC; nWidth, nHeight: Integer; Status: Byte; Color: COLORREF): HICON;
var
  lpbi: PBITMAPINFO;
  lpBits: Pointer;
  hMaskBmp, hBmp, hOldBitmap: HBITMAP;
  hMemDC: HDC;
  OldFnt, Fnt: HFONT;
  Sts: string;
  R: TRect;
  IconInfo: TIconInfo;
  Icon: HICON;
begin
  Result := 0;

  GetMem(lpbi, SizeOf(TBITMAPINFOHEADER) + SizeOf(TRGBQuad) * 256);

  try
    with lpbi^.bmiHeader do
    begin
      biSize := SizeOf(TBITMAPINFOHEADER);
      biWidth := nWidth;
      biHeight := nHeight;
      biPlanes := 1;
      biBitCount := 32; // Use a 32-bit DIB section with an alpha channel.
      biCompression := BI_RGB;
      biSizeImage := 0;
      biXPelsPerMeter := 0;
      biYPelsPerMeter := 0;
      biClrUsed := 0;
      biClrImportant := 0;
    end;

    hBmp := CreateDIBSection(DC, lpbi^, DIB_RGB_COLORS, lpBits, 0, 0);
    if hBmp = 0 then
      RaiseLastOSError;

    try
      hMemDC := CreateCompatibleDC(DC);
      if hMemDC = 0 then
        RaiseLastOSError;

      try
        hOldBitmap := SelectObject(hMemDC, hBmp);
        if hOldBitmap = 0 then
          RaiseLastOSError;

        try
          Sts := IntToStr(Status);
          Fnt := GetNCMFont; // Uses SystemParametersInfo to get the font used for the window titles (which I use for drawing)

          OldFnt := SelectObject(hMemDC, Fnt);
          R := TRect.Create(0, 0, nWidth, nHeight);
          SetBkMode(hMemDC, TRANSPARENT);
          SetTextColor(hMemDC, Color);
          DrawTextEx(hMemDC, PWideChar(Sts), -1, R,
            DT_CENTER or DT_VCENTER or DT_SINGLELINE or DT_NOCLIP, nil);

          hMaskBmp := CreateBitmap(nWidth, nHeight, 1, 1, nil);

          IconInfo.fIcon := TRUE;
          IconInfo.xHotspot := 0;
          IconInfo.yHotspot := 0;
          IconInfo.hbmMask := hMaskBmp;
          IconInfo.hbmColor := hBmp;

          Icon := CreateIconIndirect(IconInfo);
          if Icon = 0 then
            RaiseLastOSError;

          Result := Icon;
        finally
          SelectObject(hMemDC, hOldBitmap);
          SelectObject(hMemDC, OldFnt);
          DeleteObject(Fnt);
        end;
      finally
        DeleteDC(hMemDC);
      end;
    finally
      DeleteObject(hBmp);
      DeleteObject(hMaskBmp);
    end;
  finally
    FreeMem(lpbi);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Curious why you are doing this in straight Win32 API instead using the `TBitmap` and `TIcon` classes, which have transparency properties.

Answer (score 0):

To make a transparent icon, you need to use the `hbmMask` bitmap to "mask out" the pixels of the `hbmColor` bitmap which you want to be transparent. But you are not doing that. You are creating an empty 1x1 bitmap for the `hbmMask` so nothing in `hmbColor` is getting masked out.

For a color icon, the `hbmColor` and `hbmMask` bitmaps must be the same dimensions, per the [`ICONINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-iconinfo) documentation:

> For color icons, the hbmMask and hbmColor bitmaps are the same size, each of which is the size of the icon.

And per Raymond Chen's blog:

[The evolution of the ICO file format, part 2: Now in color!](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101019-00/?p=12503)

> For pixels you want to be transparent, set your mask to white and your image to black. For pixels you want to come from your icon, set your mask to black and your image to the desired color.

So, in your case:

- create your `hbmColor` bitmap and fill it with a unique background color (ie, Fuchsia is a common choice), then draw on it as needed.
- Then, create the `hbmMask` bitmap with the same dimensions as `hbmColor`. For each pixel in `hbmColor`, if it has the background color then set the corresponding `hbmMask` pixel to white, otherwise set it to black.
- Then create the icon with the 2 bitmaps.

---

To create a "semi-transparent" (ie alpha-blended) icon is *mostly* the same approach. The difference is that:

- the `hbmColor` bitmap must be a 32bit DIB with an alpha channel (use [`BITMAPV5HEADER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapv5header) with [`CreateDIBSection()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdibsection))
- the `hbmMask` bitmap must be empty.

See [MS KB Q318876: How To Create an Alpha Blended Cursor or Icon in Windows XP](https://ftp.zx.net.nz/pub/archive/ftp.microsoft.com/MISC/KB/en-us/318/876.HTM).

I just realized that you are creating a 32bit color bitmap. But I don't see you filling its background or alpha channel with any pixel data before drawing the text onto it.

Comment: I was hoping that there would be someone who would help me fix the code (to create the bitmap for the mask right, and what about semi-transparency?...) but I will try to study these in more depth, maybe I will still be able to achieve it myself...:)

Comment: What fun would that be if I just gave you the code? You learn more by doing it yourself. In any case, I updated my answer with more information.

Comment: Thanks, @Remy! I translated the code from MSDN (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-cursors) that demonstrates creating a cursor with alpha at runtime as you mentioned, but this code implements Semi-transparency on all parts of the icon, and I'm looking for a way to create a transparent icon with an opaque caption (which includes alpha for anti-aliasing). Should I create 2 bitmaps, one with a background color and a caption, and the other (for the mask) with a black background color and a white caption at the same position as the caption in the color bitmap?

Comment: You don't use the mask bitmap when the color bitmap has an alpha channel. But I don't see you filling the alpha channel with any data prior to drawing the text